# SQLAlchemy Messing Up Alias In Primary Join

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

For some reason, SQLAlchemy is joining in the target table for my relationship in the secondary join but referencing it with the wrong alias in the primary join.

Here's the python in the Child class:

```
fact_row = relationship(
        Fact,
        secondary=Parent.__table__
        primaryjoin=and_(
            foreign(child_date_member) == remote(Fact.date_member),
            foreign(Parent.id) == remote(parent_id)),
        secondaryjoin=and_(
            remote(Fact.dimension_1) == foreign(Parent.dimension_1),
            remote(Fact.dimension_2) == foreign(Parent.dimension_2),
            remote(Fact.dimension_3) == foreign(Parent.dimension_3),
        viewonly=True)
```

Here's the SQL output for the joins:

```
FROM child
LEFT OUTER JOIN (parent AS parent_1
JOIN fact AS fact_1 ON
    fact_1.dimension_1 = parent_1.dimension_1
    AND fact_1.dimension_2 = parent_1.dimension_2
    AND fact_1.dimension_3 = parent_1.dimension_3) ON
    parent_1.id = child.parent_id
    AND child.child_date_member = fact.date_member
```

Here's what would work:

```
FROM child
LEFT OUTER JOIN (parent AS parent_1
JOIN fact AS fact_1 ON
    fact_1.dimension_1 = parent_1.dimension_1
    AND fact_1.dimension_2 = parent_1.dimension_2
    AND fact_1.dimension_3 = parent_1.dimension_3) ON
    parent_1.id = child.parent_id
    AND child.child_date_member = fact_1.date_member
```

How do I get SQLAlchemy to use the right alias for the child table in the primary join? Right now, it's failing because it can't find the unaliased child table in the query.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the question.

Comment: Are you getting an error. If so, please share

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?